# Association with multiple classes

Tags: class, uml, associations, class-diagram, tool-uml

Can two classes each have an association with a third class?

For example: Game object has position, and character also has position, shown below

[image: click here to see the UML example]

I understand association class can contain another class

Comment: What are you *really* asking? Of course a class can have multiple associations, but I feel that isn't your real question.

Comment: thanks. if game object has position, and character also has position, is my UML digram correct in the picture?

Comment: Well, of course. What would be your issue??

Comment: Except that `Position` might be better of modelled as a datatype, not a class. In that case you would use it as a type of an attribute instead of using an association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes can be associated with as many other classes as necessary.

Your diagram correctly represents the fact that both a `GameObject` and a `Character` have a `Position`. You should however either remove the arrow, or make sure that the arrow head is open (if you want to say that the association is navigablle, i.e. promise that both classes can find their position efficiently at run-time).

The only case where there are resistriction is when you use composite aggregation, but it is not the case here.

***Important remark:**   the term "association class" refers to a different concept, and not simply that a class is used in an association. The same ***association class*** cannot be used for several associations because the association class is an association. But you don't have this problem here. If you want to know more about this tricky case, see this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67048791/3723423)*

Comment: You should consider to talk about Geert's suggestion using a datatype!

Comment: @qwerty_so if the position was x,y coordinates or gps coordinates, I would for sure advise on a datatype in view of the value semantics. However, in a game the position could also refer to a tile on a board with reference semantics (i.e. a distict identity beyond the value) (and it is then important to know if several instance are linked with the same position instance). I'd therefore prefer not to mislead OP with assumptions which might not be founded.